# how to set dio package in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to create flutter apps for downloading files from internet but when i use the [dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)  ,
I get the error ; The named parameter 'onProgress' isn't defined , what should I do?

my function

```
 Future<void> downloadFile() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();

    try {
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      await dio.download(imgUrl, "${dir.path}/myimage.jpg",
          onProgress: (rec, total) {
            print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");

            setState(() {
              downloading = true;
              progressString = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
            });
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      downloading = false;
      progressString = "Completed";
    });
    print("Download completed");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `onProgress` with `onReceiveProgress`.

Always check the function implementation when issues like this occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for the `download` method in Dio 4.0.0 is the following:

```dart
Future<Response> download(
    String urlPath,
    savePath, {
    ProgressCallback? onReceiveProgress,
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
    CancelToken? cancelToken,
    bool deleteOnError = true,
    String lengthHeader = Headers.contentLengthHeader,
    data,
    Options? options,
  });
```

So you should use `onReceiveProgress` instead of `onProgress`.

### Background information

`onProgress` was the initial parameter that was used when the Dio package was created. This [has been changed in the v2.0.14 release](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/commit/df957458cccd373f40be29d20b57a80731777cd7#diff-7df48d4320f935f208e2ae340fdaae85f01e7b3e92afeb5cca76ca453179b9acR367). It seems like [a small part of the initial code docs](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/dio.dart#L221-L234) remained intact since that release.

If that is what confused you, it might be a good thing to open an issue on the Dio GitHub project.